# How can I show data correctly in a UITableViewController with Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building something like an "instagram" app with posts with pictures. I am using Firebase to store/retrieve data.

My issue comes because the posts are shown kind of in a random way. For example, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the first post is shown at indexPath[0], the next post is [1], but the next one which should be at [2], it shows at [0].

I will copy paste the most relevant code for the issue:

Here is the class where I retrieve the Scores:

```
////// Arrays to store the data
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
photomealArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
keysArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // Reference to know what post should be scored. 


// Reference to the Database
self.storageRef = [[FIRStorage storage] reference];
FIRDatabaseReference *rootRef= [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:@"https://XXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/"];


// Query all posts
[[rootRef child:@"Posts"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if(snapshot.exists){

        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
        for (NSString *key in dict) {

            // Query all users to show the Name of the person who posts
            [[rootRef child:@"Users"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull Usersnapshot) {

                if(Usersnapshot.exists){
                    NSDictionary *Userdict = Usersnapshot.value;
                    for (NSString *Userkey in Userdict) {


                        NSString *Users_UserID = [Userdict[Userkey] valueForKey:@"UserID"];
                        NSString *UserID = [dict[key] valueForKey:@"UserID"];
                        // If the userID matches with the person who posts, then add it to the array
                        if([Users_UserID isEqualToString:UserID]) [nameArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Userdict[Userkey] valueForKey:@"Name"]]];

                    }
                }

            }];

            UIImage *mealPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:[dict[key] valueForKey:@"PostPhoto"]]]];

            NSString *Score = [dict[key] valueForKey:@"Score"];
            NSString *PostKeys = [dict[key] valueForKey:@"KeyforPost"];
            if([Score isEqual:@"null"]) [scoreArray addObject:@"0"]; else [scoreArray addObject:Score];
            [photomealArray addObject:mealPhoto];
            [keysArray addObject:PostKeys];

        }

    }
} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

If I quit and relaunch the app, the new post will be stored in whatever index is "empty" starting from [0], which is what it is expected.

This is how the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` looks like:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

FeedTableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone){

    if([score.text intValue] >= -1 && [score.text intValue] <= 1 && ![score.text  isEqual: @""]){

            NSString *keyforcell = [keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSLog(@"key a usar :%@", keyforcell);

             ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:@"https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com"];


            [[[[self.ref child:@"Posts"] child:keyforcell] child:@"Score"] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[score.text intValue]]];

            [[[[self.ref child:@"Posts"] child:keyforcell] child:@"Rated"] setValue:@"YES"];

            [scoreArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[score.text intValue]] atIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

}
```

I have tried to play with `observeSingleEventOfType` and `observeEventType` because maybe this has to do with the fact that the single one is only called once. Also I've thought that `viewDidLoad()` is triggered after the cell is selected, but It shouldn't. Also, I think it has to do with the NSMutableArrays, but I am not completely sure

Can anyone help me out ?

**UPDATE** : I got to know that neither Firebase nor NSDictionary returns/stored sorted data, so my guess is that my issue has something to do with sorting the items. I got to know about `orderbykey` and `orderbyvalue` but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to see what your issue is, but you should not forget there is no arrays in Firebase Database. The only collection type is dictionary, and dictionaries has no key order.

You should consider a sorting system on your objects, instead of directly adding them to arrays.

Comment: yeah you are right :) but.....i never said that there are arrays in Firebase. I mean i know that the queries returned need to be stores  in a dictionary. Just to clarify, the issue is that when the posts are loaded in the viewdidload() (after creation) it shows in random cells. I think it has to do with the NSMutableArrays, but i am not 100% sure

Comment: "it shows in random cells" >> this exactly sounds like your are relying on the order of keys in dictionary object, which does not exist. You are using `for (NSString *key in dict)` which cannot guarantee any order.

Comment: thats a good point actually. Since an NSDictionary doesnt gurantee that the items are sorted, then the items wont always be sorted in the NSMutablearray ( for my case ). So what i should do is to sort the keys-values in the Dict in the same way as they are stored in Firebase, isnt it ?

Comment: "the same way as they are stored in Firebase" >> They are not sorted in Firebase either, even though they may appear so. Just because they have some keys like `0`, `1` and `2`, it does not mean they are sorted. I repeat for the 3rd time :)  "Dictionaries cannot be sorted". First, you should understand this simple fact, and then you can decide on a way to sort your objects. You may use key values or any other info inside your objects. This depends on your app logic.